# How to concat an object at particular index in Array using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have array like **arr = [object1, object2, object3]**. I removed 1 index so array will be **arr = [object1, object3],** and again i want to add removed object2 at it's previous place like **arr = [object1, object2, object3].** Please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried?

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=example)

Comment: Do you have a copy of the removed variable

Comment: @JinsPeter,  No i don't have copy of removed variable.

Comment: What is the reason why you have to remove it and then add it back later. What will you do with `arr` or the remaining objs in it that requires this step?

Comment: @HimanshuTanwar, Yes i tried many thing now i am simply removing object2 using splice and index like - arr.splice(index, 1);  and adding again it using concat like - arr = arr.concat(object2); but it's adding Object2 at the last, but it's previous index was 1 , so i want to add it again it at index 1.

Comment: @AbhaySharma So You need to undo you operation??

Comment: @AbhaySharma, Is that an Undo function you need on your array. Show your use case.

Comment: @AbhaySharma before removing object from array store index in temp var iable and use splice to add that object at particular index that is stored in temp.

Comment: @t.niese, Suppose i have four check box including select all (Check box), as i will check select all i will get an arrayList containing three object like -arr= [object1, object2, object2], every object has value in key- value pair. And i unchecked 2nd check box , so Object2 will be remove from arrayList now my array is arr = [Object1, Object3]. if again i will check 2nd check box so, i will be add in my List, using concat it is adding it in last index, again if i uncheck 2nd it's removing Object3 but it should remove Object2 , if i will add it at same index, so remove will work perfectly.

Comment: This is an important information, because your approach would only _work_ it wont uncheck more then one checkbox at a time. I don't think that this is a good and error save aproach to solve your problem. You should ask a new question that includes the information what you want to achieve, because the answers here are correct according to your actual question, but wont solve you real problem.

Comment: @AbhaySharma did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary variable that holds `arr[object3]` then remove it from the array. Then add both objects to the array one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Array.splice() of VanillaJS

```
//Fn syntax

Array.prototype.Splice = function([indexOfRemovedElt],[No.Of Elts to Remove],<Any Object/Objects you want to add at the same position seperated by comma>)
```

In Your case let array be arr

```
var arr= [1,2,3,4,5];
```

let j be the index of element u need to remove and add.
to save and remove u use,

```
var saved = arr[j];
```

to remove

```
arr.splice(j,[noOfelts]=1);
```

to Add again

```
arr.splice(j,0,saved);
```

Comment: Don't answer badly written questions, it just encourages them and others like them to ask more.

Comment: So thats why i got a down vote.. Dude I'm a beginner here in stackOverflow. I have some experience in JS and I'm sitting idle after completing my project. Thats why I try to answer everything. Just to keep my brain rolling

Comment: @JK., Thanks for your response .i also new at stackOverFlow and in programming. I have problem so just was trying  to explain my problem , i tried many thing , next time i will be try my best at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo using ES5 :**

```js
var object1 = {name:"object1"};
var object2 = {name:"object2"};
var object3 = {name:"object3"};
var arr = [object1, object2, object3];

var removedObj = arr.splice(1,1); // removed object2 from an array.

console.log(arr); // [object1, object3]

var addRemovedObj = arr.splice(1,0,removedObj[0]);

console.log(arr); // [object1, object2, object3]
```

**Demo using ES6 :**

```js
let object1 = {name:"object1"};
let object2 = {name:"object2"};
let object3 = {name:"object3"};
let arr = [object1, object2, object3];

let removedObj = arr.splice(1,1); // removed object2 from an array.

console.log(arr); // [object1, object3]

arr = [object1, ...removedObj, object3];

console.log(arr); // [object1, object2, object3]
```